# How to Insert MenuItem to Taskbar Right Click Context Menu

Tags: c#, winforms, registry, contextmenu, taskbar

In C# Winform, do we have a way to add a custom cascading menu and menu items to Taskbar context menu?

The prefer solution would be that I can just add some entries in Windows Registry. But so far I can't find that location just yet.

[image]

Comment: are you trying to create a static or dynamic sub-menu? Either way have a look at the ContextMenuStrip component

Comment: It will be dynamic. Here in the picture, `iTunes` can add itself to Toolbars. I'm trying to have something like `MyTools` Menu and later depending on what other components users install the name would show up as a submenu item.